# Form validation and redirect in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am writing a simple form program, but I have issues with the registration and log in.

This is how I want it to work:

- I create a simple registration form that requires just email and password
- I want the user to fill in, and if the username doesn't exists in my local storage, it gives a registration success in the inner html and redirects the user to the login page, where the login should get the value of the registered user
- If that value tallies with what the user input on registration, redirect to a welcome page with the user's ID he input on registration
- Else give an error that says the username exists, and don't redirect the user to the login page at all.

If you don't understand the above question, check this if it makes it clearer:

- I am creating a registration form, so that if I register a user ID the first time, it gives me success and redirects to the log in. If i use that same ID again to register, it gives me an error stating that the ID has been registered.
- Now, after the user registers, he should be redirected to the login with a valid ID already submitted on registration
- If the ID entered doesn't match any of the ID's on registration, don't direct the user to the welcome page, else redirect to the welcome page and say "Welcome User xyz" with the User ID registered with from the registration page.

Below is my code:

**registeration code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <title>Registration</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container text-center mt-5">
            <h1>Welcome! Please register below</h1>
            <form action="" class="pt-3">
    
    
                <p class="text-danger message_error text-center"></p>
                <p class="text-success message_success text-center"></p>
    
    
                <div class="form-row">
                    <!-- username -->
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
                        <input maxlength="10" type="text" class="form-control p-3 username" placeholder="Enter Username"
                            required>
                    </div>
                    <!-- password -->
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control p-3 password" class="password" placeholder="Enter password"
                            maxlength="8" required>
                    </div>
                    <!-- submit -->
                    <div class="col-md-6 p-3">
                        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="w-100 btn btn-primary" onclick="redirect();">
                    </div>
                   
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="login.html"><div class="col-md-6 p-3">
            </div></a>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            const $form = document.querySelector("form");
    $form.addEventListener('submit', processRegistration);
    
    
    function processRegistration(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const $username = document.querySelector(".username").value;
        const $password = document.querySelector(".password").value;
        const $errorBox = document.querySelector(".message_error")
        const $successBox = document.querySelector(".message_success")
        $errorBox.innerHTML = "";
        $successBox.innerHTML = "";
    
    
    
        //  check if the browser supports this API
        if (localStorage != (null || undefined)) {
            // validate if username exists in our local storage
            const usernameExists = localStorage.getItem($username);
            if (usernameExists == null) {
                //    add user record to local storage
                localStorage.setItem($username, $password);
                $successBox.innerHTML = "Registration Successful";
                function redirect() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href = "login.html";
        },5000
        );
    }
    
                
    
            } else {
                $errorBox.innerHTML = "Sorry! This Username already exists";
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    
    
    
    
        </script>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

**log in code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="container text-center mt-5">
            <h1>Kindly fill in your details below, to Login</h1>
            <form action="" class="pt-3">
    
    
                <p class="text-danger message_error text-center"></p>
                <p class="text-success message_success text-center"></p>
    
    
                <div class="form-row">
                    <!-- username -->
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
                        <input maxlength="10" type="text" class="form-control p-3 username" placeholder="Enter Username"
                            required>
                    </div>
                    <!-- password -->
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control p-3 password" class="password" placeholder="Enter password"
                            maxlength="8" required>
                    </div>
                    <!-- submit -->
                    <div class="col-md-6 p-3">
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="w-100 btn btn-primary" onclick="redirect();">
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="welcome.html"><div class="col-md-6 p-3">
            </div></a>
        </div>
       <script>
           const $form = document.querySelector("form");
    $form.addEventListener('submit', processLogin);
    
    
    function processLogin(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const $username = document.querySelector(".username").value;
        const $password = document.querySelector(".password").value;
        const $errorBox = document.querySelector(".message_error")
        const $successBox = document.querySelector(".message_success")
        $errorBox.innerHTML = "";
        $successBox.innerHTML = "";
    
    
    
        //  check if the browser supports this API
        if (localStorage != (null || undefined)) {
            // validate if username exists in our local storage
            const usernameExists = localStorage.getItem($username);
            if (usernameExists == null) {
                //    add user record to local storage
                localStorage.getItem($username, $password);
                $successBox.innerHTML = "Login Successful";
    
                function redirect() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href = "welcome.html";
        },1000
        );
    }
    
            } else {
                $errorBox.innerHTML = "Sorry! This Username doesn;t exists, create a profile";
            }
        } else {
            $errorBox.innerHTML = "please update your browser :";
        }
    
    }
    
    
    
    
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**welcome page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <title>Welcome Page</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Welcome to Our Site! We are glad you're here</h1>
   <script>

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How many people do you expect to use that single computer/browser?

Comment: Just me Prof. it's just an assignment

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is in this question. Can you be more specific and maybe only provide the code that courses the problem?

Comment: @chrwahl I am creating a registration form, that if i register a user ID the first time, it gives me success and redirects to the log in. If i use that same ID again to register, it gives me an error stating that the ID has been registered. Now, after the user registers, he should be redirected to the login with a valid ID already submitted on registration, if the ID entered doesn't match any of the ID's on registration, don't direct the user to the welcome page, else redirect to the welcome page and say "Welcome User xyz" with the User ID registered with from the registration page.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I am the only person using the browser, just for an assignment. Thanks alot

Comment: You assign an event handler to the form `submit` event yet the event handler does not return a value. You have an inline call to the function `redirect` but that function is not given here and as it is assigned to the submit button might there not be a race condition between the button event and the form submit event?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I'll be glad if you can help me work on the code, I am a bit confused. Thanks

Comment: The last part of the question where you hope to display the username on the welcome page will not work as there is no way to know which item in localStorage pertains to which user unless you use another mechanism such as a cookie during login

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius     Please help me with the registration and login, I can figure that welcome page later, even though I may not necessarily put in the name of the user. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following might be of use. Rather than using the `submit` event a regular `click` event on the submit button seems appropriate? Due to security surrounding access to localStorage here on Stack I could not create a working snippet but local copies of this and all seemed to work.

**Registration:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <title>Registration</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container text-center mt-5">
            <h1>Welcome! Please register below</h1>
            
            <form method='post' name='register' class="pt-3">
                <p class="text-danger message_error text-center"></p>
                <p class="text-success message_success text-center"></p>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
                        <input name='username' maxlength="10" type="text" class="form-control p-3 username" placeholder="Enter Username" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
                        <input name='password' type="password" class="form-control p-3 password" class="password" placeholder="Enter password" maxlength="8" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 p-3">
                        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="w-100 btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="login.html">
                <div class="col-md-6 p-3"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            /*
                Some shorthand utility methods to simplify
                calls to certain functions.
            */
            const q=(n,ex)=>n.querySelector(ex);
            const qa=(n,ex)=>n.querySelectorAll(ex);
            const msg=(n,s)=>q(form,n).textContent=s;
            
            /*
                Once the form has been assigned a Name attribute
                you can easily refer to the form using the dot
                notation shown here.
            */
            const form=document.forms.register;
            
            /*
                using the shorthand method above to obtain a 
                reference to the `submit` button to which we 
                assign the event handler - bound to the click
                event.
            */
            q( form, "input[type='submit']" ).addEventListener('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                /*
                    find form elements - again if names are
                    assigned you can use the dot notation.
                */
                const username=form.username.value;
                const password=form.password.value;
                const exists=localStorage.getItem( username )!==null;
                
                if( exists ){
                    // username already exists...
                    msg('p.message_error','Sorry! This Username already exists');
                }else{
                    // add username to storage
                    localStorage.setItem(username,password);
                    msg('p.message_success','Registration Successful');
                    
                    setTimeout( ()=> window.location.replace("login.html"), 5000 );
                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Login:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <title>Login page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container text-center mt-5">
            <h1>Kindly fill in your details below, to Login</h1>
            
            <form method='post' name='login' class="pt-3">
                <p class="text-danger message_error text-center"></p>
                <p class="text-success message_success text-center"></p>
                
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
                        <input name='username' maxlength="10" type="text" class="form-control p-3 username" placeholder="Enter Username" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
                        <input name='password' type="password" class="form-control p-3 password" class="password" placeholder="Enter password" maxlength="8" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 p-3">
                        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="w-100 btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="login.html">
                <div class="col-md-6 p-3"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            const q=(n,ex)=>n.querySelector(ex);
            const qa=(n,ex)=>n.querySelectorAll(ex);
            const msg=(n,s)=>q(form,n).textContent=s;
            const form=document.forms.login;

            q( form,"input[type='submit']" ).addEventListener('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                
                const username=form.username.value;
                const password=form.password.value;
                const exists=localStorage.getItem( username )!==null;
                
                if( !exists ){
                    // username does NOT exist...
                    msg('p.message_error','Sorry! This Username doesn\'t exists, please create a profile!');
                }else{
                    // Everything OK... proceed to welcome page
                    msg('p.message_success','Login Successful');
                    
                    // Set a cookie to log which user has successfully logged in. This will be read on `welcome.html`
                    document.cookie='username='+username;
                    
                    // redirect to the welcome page
                    setTimeout( ()=>window.location.replace("welcome.html"), 5000 );
                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Welcome:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <title>Welcome Page</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Welcome to our site! We are glad you're here</h1>
   <span></span>
   <script>
        const q=(n,ex)=>n.querySelector(ex);
        const msg=(n,s)=>q(document,n).textContent=s;
        
        // read the cookie and extract the username.. no error checking here - this was for brevity
        let username=document.cookie.split(';').find( row=>row.startsWith('username') ).split('=')[1]
        
        // display some sort of message...
        msg('span',['Hi there ',username,' take a seat and make yourself comfortable'].join(''));
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot Prof. This is just what I wanted. You're the best. The code Works. Cheers